# How do I get the value of a symbol using Scala reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection

Using Scala reflection, you can get the value of some element within the AST. For example when I want to get the value of some String within the AST I can use the following statement which works perfectly fine:

`a.tree.children.tail.collect({case Literal(Constant(id: String)) => id}).head`

However, when the value I want to access is a scala.Symbol instead of a String, the statement above does not return the value:

`a.tree.children.tail.collect({case Literal(Constant(id: Symbol)) => id}).head`

My question: scala.Symbol appears to be something else than a Literal Constant in the AST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print trees

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

println(showRaw(reify {
  "aaa"
}.tree)) // Literal(Constant("aaa"))

println(showRaw(reify {
  'aaa
}.tree)) 
// Apply(Select(Ident(scala.Symbol), TermName("apply")), List(Literal(Constant("aaa"))))
```

Try

```
case q"Symbol.apply(${Literal(Constant(id: String))})" => id
```

or

```
case Apply(Select(Ident(TermName("Symbol")), TermName("apply")), List(Literal(Constant(id: String)))) => id
```

You can look how they work with `Symbol`s in Shapeless

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L142-L146

Comment: Thanks for this information. The 2 solutions you give still don't work for me. When I print the showRaw output I get the following: Apply(Select(Select(Ident(scala), scala.Symbol), TermName("apply")), List(Literal(Constant("aaa")))) however matching on that doesn't work either ...

Comment: On a side not, I find it strange that your first solution does not work for me since that is exactly what is in the AST

Comment: @Maarten What is your version of Scala? What exactly is `a`?

Comment: Scala version 2.12.8 and a is an Annotation

Comment: My bad, turns out your first solution using the quasiquote works perfectly. Thanks!